# Google Play reject app but app status is in review

Tags: google-play-console

app rejected due to "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission" being used by file_open plugin. I used file_open_safe plugin instead and submitted again. Now app bundle permissions doesn't have this permission. Tried submitting new version (1.1.1) I still got app rejected mail, but submitted app (1.1.1) status is still in review. tried another 1.1.2 and got same mail and status still in review.

**1.1.1 Permissions**

[image]

**Releases**

[image]